# Laravel display pdf in storage

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, storage, laravel-8

I'm new to Laravel and I'm currently working on a web application in localhost (MAMP on Windows). I heard that if you want to make files publicly accessible you should store them in the public folder inside the storage. This is my code for storing (for example test.pdf):

```
$filename = $request->filename;
$file = $request->file;

file_put_contents(storage_path('app\public').'\\uploads\\clients\\1\\2\\".$filename, file_get_contents($file));
```

In my Windows explorer the file "test.pdf" has been stored here: *\public\storage\uploads\clients\1\2*

Now I created following route in **web.php**:

```
Route::get('/file',  ['as' => 'home.showFile', 'uses' => 'HomeController@showFile']);
```

Here's the HomeController's showFile function, to display the stored file:

```
public function showFile()
    {
      return response()->file(asset('\uploads\clients\1\2\test.pdf')); 
    }
```

When I visit http://localhost/file following error message occurs (I tried with forward and back slashes):
[image]

I visited many websited and forums but couldn't get it to work... the file is accessible with following link though: *localhost/storage/uploads/clients/1/2/test.pdf*

Can somebody help me how to display a file from storage?

Comment: is this a windows server or why are you using backslashes insted of forward slashes?

Comment: @LarsStegelitz Yes it's a local windows server with MAMP. It still doesn't work with the back slashes, so i tried it with forward slashes :)

Comment: The URL is suspicious... `http://localhost/\uploads\clients\..` The web does use the forward slash `/`, I would advise to do the same. Windows can handle slashes in the  file system.

Comment: @LarsStegelitz It still doesnt work. See updated answer

Comment: According to the documentation `storage_path()` is supposed to get the storage path. You'd have to check your config files, how that is configured. 
What about the other options, `public_path` or `resource_path`? What does `storage_path('app\public')` returns?